# It is not possible to retrieve crawl information as the system is configured in a way that limits access to this information

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, search

I created a product catalog site collection in SharePoint 2013 on-premise.

When I goto catalog settings, I seeing following error:

> It is not possible to retrieve crawl information as the system is configured in a way that limits access to this information.

I have done full crawl on the site collection and I have also set the content source to crawl continous.

Any ideas on what is causing the search crawl information to not show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can goto the List settings and from there goto  Advanced settings of that list which has catalog.
Click Reindex List button

On Central admin, Do a full crawl